# Type Annotations: TypeVar: Bound, Problem

Tags: python, types, mypy, python-typing

In the Python [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic), we find:

```
T = TypeVar('T')              # Can be anything
S = TypeVar('S', bound=str)   # Can be any subtype of str
A = TypeVar('A', str, bytes)  # Must be exactly str or bytes
```

We find also this code:

```
def repeat(x: T, n: int) -> Sequence[T]:
    """Return a list containing n references to x."""
    return [x]*n


def print_capitalized(x: S) -> S:
    """Print x capitalized, and return x."""
    print(x.capitalize())
    return x


def concatenate(x: A, y: A) -> A:
    """Add two strings or bytes objects together."""
    return x + y
```

Adding then this line of code

```
print(concatenate("hello ", "world"))
```

should be perfectly oky with mypy and it is!

I define now a class:

```
class sstr(str):
    pass
```

and use this code:

```
s1 = sstr("hello ")
s2 = sstr("world")
print(concatenate(s1, s2))
```

In the definition of A it says: "Must be exactly str or bytes"
s1 and s2 are not exactly str or bytes but sstr, which is a subclass of str.
So to my mind, mypy should raise an error, but it says:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Apparantly, I must have got something wrong.

I even tried it with a class

```
class sstr(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self + other + "_42"
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return "foo"
```

What did I get wrong? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"exactly" is misleading here. In general, the type system assumes Liskov substitutability. So a subtype `S` of a type `T` is always acceptable in the place of `T`. The "exactly" is referring to a specific behavior. When you use a constrained instead of bound type variable*, the result is always either `str` or `bytes`, so even if you provide a `MyStr`, it returns a `str` as far as the type checker is concerned:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T", str, bytes)

class MyString(str):
    pass


def alphabetize(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    if a >= b:
        return a
    else:
        return b


c0 = alphabetize("foo", "bar")
c1 = alphabetize("foo", MyString("bar"))
c2 = alphabetize(MyString("foo"), MyString("bar"))

reveal_type(c0)
reveal_type(c1)
reveal_type(c2)
```

Using `mypy` gives:

```
test_typing.py:20: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
test_typing.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
test_typing.py:22: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Here is how this is described in [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#type-variableshttps://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#type-variables), the first PEP that described how the type system was going to work and the idea of type variables:

> A constrained type variable ranges only over constrains t1, etc.
> exactly; subclasses of the constrains are replaced by the most-derived
> base class among t1,

However, that isn't how it works when you give it an upper bound:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=str)

class MyString(str):
    pass


def alphabetize(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    if a >= b:
        return a
    else:
        return b


c0 = alphabetize("foo", "bar")
c1 = alphabetize("foo", MyString("bar"))
c2 = alphabetize(MyString("foo"), MyString("bar"))

reveal_type(c0)
reveal_type(c1)
reveal_type(c2)
```

And `mypy` gives you:

```
test_typing.py:20: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
test_typing.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
test_typing.py:22: note: Revealed type is "test_typing.MyString"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Note, in the condition where you mix types , the result is the narrowest common type possible. Consider a situation where you have a deeper inheritance hierarchy:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=str)

class SpecialString(str):
    pass

class SuperSpecialString(SpecialString):
    pass

def alphabetize(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    if a >= b:
        return a
    else:
        return b


c0 = alphabetize(SpecialString("foo"), SuperSpecialString("bar"))
c1 = alphabetize("foo", SuperSpecialString("bar"))
c2 = alphabetize(SuperSpecialString("foo"), SuperSpecialString("bar"))

reveal_type(c0)
reveal_type(c1)
reveal_type(c2)
```

And here, `mypy` gives:

```
test_typing.py:22: note: Revealed type is "test_typing.SpecialString"
test_typing.py:23: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
test_typing.py:24: note: Revealed type is "test_typing.SuperSpecialString
```

Comment: Misleading Python docs strikes again!

Comment: @metatoaster sort of, but it is referring to a specific behavior that is important to understand. So while it *accepts*any subtype as the constrained type (because subtypes *always* count where you require the parent type), it still considers it *exactly the constrained type*

Comment: Yeah, how subtypes work is pretty much well known to someone who has developed on Python like I, but when a language has been advertised as newbie friendly and then coming across documentation like this leads to more questions than answers. I do hope docs.python put more clarity on that e.g. including the phrase "and their subtypes" or just simply erase the word "exactly" would be a useful change that removes much of these confusion for newbies.

Comment: @metatoaster please consider opening a documentation PR for this page if you consider this important for future readers.

Comment: @SUTerliakov well, I will be very blunt here - maybe when the whole type hinting system within Python becomes more properly baked, when they don't come with so many edge cases that can be triggered trivially ([examples I've documented](https://gist.github.com/metatoaster/e8619d588b6a8bac2db0ebfaf83d4809)), I might consider doing that.  I personally have moved onto another (statically typed) language that does types properly when I actually want what type hints provide - I just don't find value (or fun) in using type hints in Python.